# Overlay two images using WriteableBitmap

Tags: silverlight, bitmap, writeablebitmap

I have got two images, say png and jpeg and I need to overlay them.
In WPF it can be done by DrawingGroup (unavailable in SL). I guess it might be done
with WriteableBitmap instead. Do you have any idea how to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `Grid` instead:-

```
 <Grid>
    <Image Source="MyPic1.png" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    <Image Source="MyPic2.jpg" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
 </Grid>
```